# line integral, then mass of the line

Tags: calculus

I have a line is lying along the curve parameterized at $x = 5cos (t), y = 5sin (t), z = 2t$ for $0≤t≤\pi$.

What is the mass of the wire if its mass density is given by$ ρ (x, y, z) = z?$

I have tried this for a long time, cant seem to figure out the correct answer, im sure its simple tho.

How do i calculate the mass of this wire, and how do i calculate it the correct way?

Comment: What about the previous one? I suggest to solve at least one problem. Can you proceed by the hints?

Comment: yeah im trying, but still cant get it right. how do i do it completly? so i can try to backtrack it and then figure out what i did wrong/right ish.

Comment: please try to solve and show your work here, I will take  alook to it.

Comment: I've tried a lot. and im not sure how to type it all in here aswell, im new here. could u please show me instead then i can se what i did wrong

Comment: you should use https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: as an alternative you can upload a pic of your work

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

- consider the parametrization $((x(t),y(t),z(t))\quad t\in [0,\pi]$
- set up and calculate the line integral $\int_L \rho ds=\int_{0}^{\pi} z(t)\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2+z'(t)^2}dt$